# I'd like to create a list: If cell contains value "Training Examples", pull the associated Training Example. Ideally this list only contains matches

Tags: arrays, list, if-statement, vlookup

I have a list of outputs, as well as a flag on some of these (maybe 10%) where I've determined that they're good 'Training Examples'.

I'd like to create a list of these Training Examples, excluding any gaps, so that I don't have to filter or sift through a long list of outputs.

E:E contains the output and M:M contains the flag i.e. 'Training Examples' and not all of these rows will contain this value, in those cases I'd want to omit it altogether, ideally the list will only contain matches.

I've attempted to work using IF / VLOOKUP to try and identify this behaviour, however, to no avail. I also can't find anything where someone has tried to present a list of matches, but exclude any non-matches altogether.